# How to convert string to date in AWS Glue

Tags: pyspark, etl, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a csv file in AWS S3, when I execute a crawler the field with dates like `01/01/2016 04.21` is taken as a string in AWS glue.

How can I change it to date type?

I tried with the "modify schema" button in AWS Glue but it ends up having a blank field.

Comment: what is the format of the date column in modified schema

Answer (score 2):

Convert the dynamic frame to a Pyspark dataframe and use Pyspark for everything. easier:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, col

df= dyf.toDF()
df = df.withColumn(col(columnname), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(columnname),"dd/MM/yyyy hh.mm")))
```